# Does osql.exe lock tables while exporting?

Tags: sql-server

While I am exporting a table from SQL Server using osql.exe, is the table locked? Will it interfere with other processes?

I am using SQL Server Workgroup Edition (10.52.4000.0).

Answer (score 2):

`osql.exe` ( and `sqlcmd.exe` ) are just programs to send T-SQL commands to the engine.  Whether or not your tables will be *blocked* during your export will depend on what exactly it is you're doing to export them.  If you're running `SELECT` statements into a .csv with transaction isolation at no higher than the `READ COMMITTED` default level, you should only be able to encounter blocking on tables that include [BLOB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb895234.aspx) data ( like `VARCHAR( MAX )`, for instance ).  Of course, if you're just spitting out to .csv you might want to look at using `bcp.exe` instead anyway.

There will be locks placed on the tables regardless of how you're exporting the data ( Schema locks at least ), but those locks won't be an issue and cause blocking if you don't overdo your isolation level.  If you're doing a metadata only export, the locks will be placed on the metadata tables instead of the actual tables themselves.

Comment: With a default installation, even `read committed` will create locks that prevent concurrent write access (but that is - as you said - independent of the tool that is being used)

Comment: Oh, thanks for clearing that up!  I really thought it was only a concern for tables containing BLOB data, but even as I was responding I realized I wasn't *positive* about that!